# Deselecting a text box in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery search script that queries a PHP file then parses the results into an HTML div. When no query is active the text box is automatically selected but when a query is active I want it not to be automatically selected. Currently I have only been able to disable the text box which isn't what I want. How can I resolve this issue?

My jQuery script is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^=type_]').click(function(){
        type=this.id.replace('type_','');
        $('[id^=type_]').removeClass('selected');
        $('#type_'+type).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
    $('#type_search').click();
    $('#query').keyup(function(){
        var query=$(this).val();
        var url='/'+type+'/'+query+'/';
        window.location.hash=''+type+'/'+query+'/';
        document.title=$(this).val()+' - My Search';
        $('#results').show();
        if(query==''){
            window.location.hash='';
            document.title='My Search';
            $('#results').hide();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:url,
            dataType:'html',
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#query').prop('disabled',true);
            },
            success:function(results){
                $('#results').html(results);
            }
        });
    });
    if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#'+type+'/')==0){
        query=window.location.hash.replace('#'+type+'/','').replace('/','');
        $('#query').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
    }
    $('#query').focus();
});
```

Comment: Can't you just remove `$('#query').focus();` and add `autofocus` to the field?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but if you reload the page and load data into the `#query` textbox, can't you use `$('#query').val()` to check it's length and if it's empty do `focus()`?

Comment: See my answer I posted, I'll update that if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the 'answer' version of the comment I just made. If you use `$('#query').val().length` you can grab the length of the value in the textbox, like so:

```
var textlength = $('#query').val().length;

if(textlength <= 0)
    $('#query').focus();
else
    $('#query').blur();
```

I don't think the `.blur();` is really required, but it can't hurt either.

---

**edit #1:** Okay, I assume you have a page where there is a search box and a `div`-tag where your items are stored (which you do by AJaX). Also I assume that when you then hit F5 (thus reload the whole page) your page will reload and there will already be data in the search box (by PHP or earlier JavaScript statements). Then you can replace your current `$('#query').focus();`, with the code I posted above.

---

**edit #2:** I've just re-read your code, and I think replacing `$('#query').focus();` with my code should do the trick exactly like you want.

Comment: It depends, when do you want to deselect the textbox exactly? At page load (meaning full page load) or when there is an AJaX request/result?

Comment: I updated my answer, please read over it to see if it will fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#query').blur()` to remove the focus ( http://api.jquery.com/blur/ )

#### update:

If you want the ajax requests to be sent (and the textbox lose focus) only when you think the user has pause typing you can start a renewing timeout to the `keyup` event and only send the ajax request when it fires. this way you can rather safely blur the textbox:

```
var queryPauseTimeout;
.
.
.
.

$('#query').keyup(function(){
    if (queryPauseTimeout)
       clearTimeout(queryPauseTimeout);

    queryPauseTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var query=$('#query').val();
    var url='/'+type+'/'+query+'/';
    window.location.hash=''+type+'/'+query+'/';
    document.title=$('#query').val()+' - My Search';
    $('#results').show();
    if(query==''){
        window.location.hash='';
        document.title='My Search';
        $('#results').hide();
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:url,
        dataType:'html',
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#query').prop('disabled',true);
        },
        success:function(results){
            $('#results').html(results);
        }
    });
,5000);
```

.
.
.
.

Comment: I have updated my answer to perhaps better suit the situation